# Kyocera TASKalfa 3252ci - eMail sending suddenly stopped working

Tags: email, printer, scanner

Our Kyocera "Scan to eMail" facility suddenly stopped working.

I checked the email account settings it uses in Thunderbird email client and it showed a problem (error message after sending saying - it could not save the sent emails).

I checked with CPANEL in the hosting account and it showed SPF problems - which the hosting provider then fixed for me and the Thunderbird problem went away, but the Kyocera still not working - no change same error 0x1101

Appreciate any advice/help/info to help explain or get resolved

Using SMTP Port 465
Using SSL/TLS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Could not save" has nothing to do with SPF, generally, but – does CPANEL give you access to the mail server's logs? (Is this a dedicated server, or a shared web hosting plan?) How old is the device, how old is its firmware? Could it be that it doesn't support TLSv1.2 and your hosting provider just switched off the obsolete TLSv1.0? Could it be that your hosting provider switched to a new CA for TLS certificates and the device doesn't recognize it?

Comment: @user1686 thanks, I'll check those logs. Its a shared hosting server. I felt it was some firmware obsolesence issue but didn't know what - so something to check. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be niche, but if you have confirmed that all of your settings are correct but still receive the x1101 error, check your ARP table. We had someone plug in a device that ended up having the same IP as our printer. Once unplugged everything went back to normal. Hopefully this helps someone :)